# Breaking an Access/Excel table into multiple Excel sheets based on a field value

Tags: excel, ms-access, export, field

I have a table that groups sets of values based on a document they came from. The table is currently in Excel, but could easily be imported into Access if it's easier from there.

```
doc value1  value2  value3
foo 29037   1098273 1023978
foo 1029387 109178  10918
bar 102893  101982  102907
biz 1023894 1908237 1023894
bar 102734  997124  834347
```

What is the easiest way to export these values into three different Excel workbooks (foo.xlsx, bar.xlsx, and biz.xlsx), with the column headings and values in the original table?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Is this on going, or a one-time thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ADO with Excel ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819 ), but this would be very simple indeed with Access, [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164087%28v=office.10%29.aspx) and a query.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Doc='Foo'
```